# Parsing data-forge DataFrame with missing data

Tags: node.js, missing-data, data-forge

I have a CSV file formatted like this and containing missing data:

```
time,col1,col2
0,12.3,99.2
1,,101.0
2,10.5,101.4
3,,102.5
4,11.9,
```

I'm using data-forge-js to read the data from CSV and convert it into floats:

```
const stringDF = dataForge.fromCSV(csvData);
const parsedDF = stringDF.parseFloats(stringDF.getColumnNames());
```

But this results an empty dataframe because (I assume) there are missing values in the data. It works when there are no missing values. How can I insert NaNs or some stand-in value for missing data?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting confused by the lazy evaluation of DataFrames in data-forge. I needed to call `parsedDF.bake()` to force evaluation so that when it's printed in the console I could see the parsed data.

Working solution here: https://runkit.com/shrinkinguniverse/parse-dataframe-with-missing-data-using-data-forge

```
const dataForge = require('data-forge');

csvString = `time,col1,col2
0,12.3,99.2
1,,101.0
2,10.5,101.4
3,,102.5
4,11.9,`

const stringDF = dataForge.fromCSV(csvString);
let parsedDF = stringDF.parseFloats(stringDF.getColumnNames());
parsedDF = parsedDF.bake(); //Needed to force lazy evaluation to evaluate.
console.log(parsedDF);
```